# How to reenable full access to a drive's folders and files in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

At my PC with Windows 10, I wanted to experiment (unfortunately!) with the accessibility of the entire disk (not fortunately the main one) and through `properties/security/advanced/Edit/type:Deny` I made its contents (folders and files) inaccessible.

When I tried to restore the original state with the reverse process (`type:allow`) I got many error messages

> An error occurred...
>
> the filename
>
> Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied

And at the end for each folder it asks me again to change permissions with errors and in general I have lost access to most folders and files.

Can someone guide me to restore full access to all the contents of the disk?

Comment: Did you try this with the built-in Administrator or a different Administrator account?

Comment: With the my usual account that has administrative rights

Comment: Try the built-in Administrator account. You will have to enable it before you try to login since it’s disabled by default

Comment: How can I switch to build-in administrator account, please ?

Comment: You need to enable it before you can log into it.  How both those actions are performed are very well documented.

Comment: I switched to build-in admin account but the problem remains! Ι am so desperate!

Comment: What partition did you perform this ACL modification on exactly? I assume it wasn’t the system partition since Windows likely wouldn’t boot if that was the case.

Comment: I did this on a second drive (not the system one) so I can boot and work normally except the access to SOME folders on the affected drive

Comment: For these folders I receive the error "You don't currently have permission to access this folder. Click continue to permanently get access to this folder". After pressing "continue" I receive the error "You have been denied permission to access this folder. To gain access to this folder you will nedd to use the security tab". Opening security tab I can see that "SYSTEM", "Administrators", "users" all have full control enabled.

Comment: PS. I just remembered that I had "denied" as another user who, because I was getting these error messages, I deleted him but the errors still persist.

Comment: Have you tried to take ownership of the folders you cannot access. You should never modify the permissions of a secondary disk, especially, if it’s an external drive. There is a reason secondary drives have the permissions they do. Modifying the ACL isn’t necessarily taking ownership of the folder. Removing the actual user which is the owner can actually cause this issue. You should be able to take ownership as an Administrator, like [this](https://windowsreport.com/failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-container/), especially if Administrators currently are on the ACL.

Comment: The second disk is also an internal HDD (the first is a SSD). I Tried to get the ownership but I failed perhaps due to wrong way that I took from internet.

Comment: @JimPapas `WinKey`+`R` → _Open_: `powershell` → `Ctrl`+`Shift`+OK → `icacls <driveletter>:` → Please add output within a code box. Simplest way to resolve is using [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) with `-s` to open a terminal as `System`, then fix the ACLs with [`icacls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls). **_Do not run any other commands from the terminal `psexec` opens as `System`**_ - use a normal terminal for executing other commands beyond `icacls`, and close the `System` terminal once done.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the operating system and I don't think I'll be able to follow your advice. Do you think that reinstalling windows (which is the most familiar procedure to me) will solve the rights problem?

Comment: Run an elevated Command Prompt (CMD) and enter the following command: "full path to the folder" /reset /t /c /l`. Try first with the folder `C:\Windows`.